# firebase cloud function http request body is empty (sending from flutter)

Tags: json, dart, google-cloud-functions

i'm playing with flutter web (dart) and try to send an http post request with a JSON body to cloud functions. Dart code:

```
var header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
var bodyData = {"text": "something"};
var body = jsonEncode(bodyData);
var response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: body);
```

but i got a empty body `{}` by calling `console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));` within cloud functions

i've already tried

```
var header = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};
var body = 'text=something';
var response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: body);
```

calling the same print statement and got (as expected): `Request body: {"text":"something"}`

it seems to me that there's something wrong with the json encoding?!